# Rails way to organize models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

So the stroy is very simple: if I have some groups of models, very closely related to each other within a each group (and not so closely between the groups) I can organize them in modules (so that each group will have its own folder in the models directory and the tables of each group will have a common prefix).

But the question is: is that way readly the Rails way or not?

Comment: Yes you can organize your models however you feel like

Comment: You can try to organize in standard Rails generator way. As ``rails g model module_name/model_name [attributes]`` it automaticaly create module with nested model.